# How to get the value of complex JavaBean

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I have a *.jrxml* file and I would like to pass some params from the code to it. I have an `Orde`r class that has fields like `double price`, `int quantity` and `Product product`. The situation is simple, when i need to pass price or quantity, I just do something like this:

```xml
<textFieldExpression class = "java.lang.Integer">
   <![CDATA[$F{quantity}]]>
</textFieldExpression>
```

The problem appears when I try to pass `product.getName()`. I tried something like:

```xml
<textFieldExpression class = "java.lang.String">
   <![CDATA[$F{product}.getName()]]>
</textFieldExpression>
```

and many others but I keep getting error: `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid :   1. Field not found : product`

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38535589/59087

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example you have a pair of JavaBeans (POJO):

```java
public class Order {

    private double price;
    private int quantity;
    private Product product;
    // public getters 
}

public class Product {

    private String name;
    // public getters 
}
```

and you declare report's datasource in the manner like this: <sup>(yes, I like *Guava*)</sup>

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource datasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(Lists.newArrayList(ImmutableList.<Order>builder()
        .add(new Order(1000.2, 10, new Product("Phone")))
        .add(new Order(10200.0, 2, new Product("Tv")))
        .build()));
```

In case using this fields declaration:

```xml
<field name="order" class="java.lang.Object">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="price" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="quantity" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="productName" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[product.name]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

you can use such expressions:

```xml
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{price}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField>
    <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField>
    <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{productName}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

---

***Note:***

- Don't forget that getters should be public
- More info: [JavaBean Data Sources](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#javabeandatasources)
- The good explanation of *_THIS* using with samples can be found in this posts:

  1. [How to access the root element of the datasource in jasperreports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6874719/876298)
  2. [Passing the List of primitive type objects as datasource for subreport](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11949333/876298)
  3. [How do I print a list of strings contained within another list in iReport?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1771864/876298)