# Populating a single report with two different java beans

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I'm new to jasper reports and I'm trying to populate a **single** report with **two** different java beans, my report has two different sections one for the patient info and the other for the medications, I created two different beans one for the medication and the other for the patient info and from my `beanFactory` class I have two methods returning a list of beans for each bean.

I'm getting  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'med' on class 'class jasperreport.Bean'`

this is the code that compiles and fills the jasper report:

```
public class or {

    public or(){

        try {
            InputStream stream= new FileInputStream("ordonanceReport.jrxml");


            JasperReport MasterReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(stream);


            Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap();
            parameters.put("ReportDataSource", new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(BeanFactory.getMedBeans()));

            JasperPrint print= JasperFillManager.fillReport(MasterReport, parameters
                ,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(BeanFactory.getInfoBeans()));
            JasperViewer.viewReport(print);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        or o= new or();
    }  
}
```

these are my two beans:
**medBean**

```
public class medBean {
    private String med="";

    public medBean(String med) {
        super();
        this.med = med;
    }

    public String getMed() {
        return med;
    }

    public void setMed(String med) {
        this.med = med;
    }


}
```

**InfoBean**

```
public class InfoBean {

    private String date="";
    private String nomPatient="";
    private String prenomPatient="";
    private String agePatient="";



    public InfoBean(String date, String nomPatient, String prenomPatient, String agePatient) {
        super();
        this.date = date;
        this.nomPatient = nomPatient;
        this.prenomPatient = prenomPatient;
        this.agePatient = agePatient;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getNomPatient() {
        return nomPatient;
    }

    public void setNomPatient(String nomPatient) {
        this.nomPatient = nomPatient;
    }

    public String getPrenomPatient() {
        return prenomPatient;
    }

    public void setPrenomPatient(String prenomPatient) {
        this.prenomPatient = prenomPatient;
    }

    public String getAgePatient() {
        return agePatient;
    }

    public void setAgePatient(String agePatient) {
        this.agePatient = agePatient;
    }

}
```

this is the bean factory class:
**BeanFactory**

```
public class BeanFactory {
    public static Collection getInfoBeans(){
        List<Bean> allbeans = new ArrayList<>();
        try { 

            allbeans.add(new Bean("12/01","gherbi","mohamed","22"));
            allbeans.add(new Bean("13/33","gherbi","Hicham","27"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return allbeans;
    }
    public static Collection getMedBeans(){
        List<medBean> allbeans = new ArrayList<>();
        try { 

            allbeans.add(new medBean("12/0dgddghd"));
            allbeans.add(new medBean("13/3bdhhsdhd"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return allbeans;
    }

}
```

I have added this line to my jasperreport file to be able to get the medBean:

```
<parameter name="ReportDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
```

and this is my Jasper report .jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
<!-- 2017-01-18T17:16:19 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ordonanceReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="6e17b895-f9d9-42b5-830b-1ef42a6369b6">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="ReportDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>

    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="nomPatient" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="prenomPatient" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="agePatient" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="med" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="139" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="195" height="30" uuid="6f3a4542-cf3d-4098-9470-b37aef5efdfd"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="22" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[الحكيم: عابد محمد الامين]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="30" width="200" height="20" forecolor="#020108" uuid="fcf14a3e-c799-48e7-865e-3e372d1429e6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="14" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Dr.ABBED Mohamed El Amine]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="35" y="50" width="145" height="20" uuid="0a058164-8f16-479f-acfa-5f1d4b086420"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="DejaVu Serif" size="14" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Chirurgien Dentiste]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="80" width="125" height="20" uuid="2cc59804-45cc-4c88-851d-eb79974be02f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified"/>
                <text><![CDATA[N° 14 Route Nationale N° 04]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="30" y="100" width="108" height="20" uuid="091aea38-23a0-48ac-b40b-18044cf46650"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Oued Fodda- CHLEF]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="38" y="120" width="100" height="18" uuid="f571acb4-2413-47c1-835c-16f09fd29023"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Tel : 027 44 79 03]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="320" y="10" width="90" height="20" uuid="bfeaf387-ba74-4e31-ad47-ef288e9f5620"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Oued-Fodda, le ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="420" y="10" width="140" height="20" uuid="aa3c34c4-f7e7-4650-b351-05d305ba9331"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="310" y="52" width="250" height="78" uuid="91636d06-0155-4a81-85f9-21e53571fccf"/>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="320" y="59" width="63" height="20" uuid="cfc38414-4030-402a-8782-7ebf95b7cb3d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nom      :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="320" y="80" width="63" height="20" uuid="2c1f37f0-67c9-4bbd-b0ed-7e4214445cea"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Prenom :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="320" y="100" width="63" height="22" uuid="7564b34c-0c52-4b96-94f8-0e5b3fd1c7ab"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Age       :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="390" y="59" width="130" height="21" uuid="12d4fae4-732d-46b9-856f-b4aab950b34c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nomPatient}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="390" y="80" width="130" height="24" uuid="24b7cbaa-4fab-497f-90fa-1476d48acd09"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{prenomPatient}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="390" y="104" width="130" height="18" uuid="f645445e-baf2-445d-b646-bbc58b433358"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{agePatient}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="180" y="6" width="140" height="44" uuid="47e85cd8-03fa-414b-ae1d-448df4222196"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="26" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Ordonnance]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="44" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="36" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="26073bf7-15a6-43e9-9b4e-4bd01b5ec2f6"/>
                <text><![CDATA[med]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="214" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="544" height="30" uuid="6cc37921-6390-4c94-9ecd-f4c8e85432b0"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{med}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="5" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="13" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I feel like there is something wrong with my assumptions here does it work this way or do I need change to something?
PS: I don't want to use a subreport, I know that that's a possibility, I want to use a single report that contains everything.

Comment: You are passing the collection of `InfoBean` as main dataset. There is no getter in this bean class for `med`. This is a reason you got an error. BTW,  I don't see how you are using the `ReportDataSource` parameter

Comment: @AlexK Yes I'm passing infoBean as the main dataset, but that's the entire point , I have put the med field in teh detail section of my report just so it can print each object you ad, I need several "med" fields to be printed into the report incontrast to just one info fields, that's why I need to sepatrate the two into two different beans. As for the ReportDataSource I actually don't know which sections of my report to modify for this to work i thought all I had to do was add it to the parameters map and pass a line in the jrxml and it would would work, as I said i'm a total JSreports noob

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value of complex JavaBean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832484/how-to-get-the-value-of-complex-javabean)

Comment: This post should help you. And this ones: [JRBeanCollectionDataSource: How to show data from the java.util.List from JavaBean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12209300/876298) & [Passing an ArrayList report shows comma every item](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40281343/876298)